# Is it bad practice to use std::max on enum types?

Tags: c++, enums

I have two `enum` objects `a` and `b`, and I would like to get the max of the two.  Here is what I have:

```
enum MyEnum {
    ZERO,
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
};

MyEnum max_val = std::max(TWO, THREE);
```

This works fine on my machine (max_val is assigned the value of THREE).  However, I want to know if this is good practice, or if it would be better to cast to `int` to do any comparison operations, like so:

```
MyEnum max_val = static_cast<MyEnum>(std::max<int>(TWO, THREE));
```

Comment: Are you asking if it's portable or not? Or whether it's a good idea or not regardless of portability?

Comment: I think there are two parts to this question: is this behavior well defined (i.e. portable) and is this good practice in general. I know that there are times when explicit casting is recommended.

Comment: Looking back, I have no idea why I wanted to do this.  Maybe there was some ordered enum like UNITS_MB, UNITS_GB, UNITS_TB...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `static_cast` - this is perfectly OK:

```
#include <algorithm>

enum MyEnum {
    ZERO,
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
};

MyEnum e = std::max( ZERO, ONE);
```

Requirements for `std::max` are at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max - values must be comparable and copy-constructible, which enum values are.

Comment: How do you know that `enums` are guaranteed to be comparable? Do they inherit all operations from their `int` counterpart? (I only ask because I haven't been able to find any documentation on using operators besides `=` and `==` with enum types)

Comment: All enums must be implemented in terms of integers - all integers are comparable. Using less-than and other relational operators on enums has been going on since the dawn of history, or at least since C was invented.

Comment: Ah got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The default underlying type of an `enum` must at least be the width of an `int` and must be an integral type. This means that using `std::max` on it is perfectly valid and well defined.

You can specify the type yourself if wanted to make sure:

```
enum MyEnum : int {
    ZERO,
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
};
```